# DRUPAL 7 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1406

Tags: drupal-7

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1406 Data too long for column 
'delta' at row 1: 
INSERT INTO {block} 
    (module, delta, theme, status, weight, region, pages, cache) 
VALUES 
    (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
     :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, 
     :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); 
Array ( 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => panels_mini 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => mini_panel_titulo_de_adminisracion
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => bartik 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => -1 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => -1 ) 
in drupal_write_record() 
(line 7013 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7.14\includes\common.inc).
```

someone can help me with this error.....

Comment: I notice, after formatting, that `:db_insert_placeholder_6` appears to be `null`.  I don't know drupal well enough to know if it relates

Answer (score 1):

The delta column in the block table is a `varchar` with a maximum length of 32 characters.

That query is trying to insert the delta value `mini_panel_titulo_de_adminisracion` which is 34 characters long.

I don't use panels so I can't really advise, except to say if you can change the name of the administration title field to something at least 2 characters shorter the error will probably go away.

If not you could try filing a bug report on the [panels issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/panels?categories=All)